# "Session Variable" in vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, session-variables

I have 4 pages with forms (VS2012). The first form fills the data based on the search. The second page is just an intermediate page which will have links to the `form 3` and `form 4`. When `form 3` is closed, this intermediate page opens up. The job of this intermediate page is to hold the variables and passes on to `form 3` and `form 4`. I am trying to use session varible instead of query string.

1. Can I create a session variables in the intermediate page which is passed from form 1 as querystring?
2. Can I read these session variables in form 3 and form 4?
3. Will I be writing the session variable in the Page_Load event?
4. What else should I be considering while using session variable?

I hope I have given all the information properly.

Comment: 1.yes 2.yes 3.yes 4.nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, you can create session variables in the intermediate page
2. Yes, you can read these session variables in anyone of anyone of the forms in your app
3. Yes, you can write add/update session variables in the page_load event
4. You should remove the session variable once you finish using them in your application

Hope this helps.

Comment: I need to have to adding to and reading form the session variable in the page_load event right?

Comment: No, it's not just limited to the Page_Load Event. You can manipulate the session variable in any page or control event.

Comment: I have "Session("PatronID") = GVPatID" in my intermediate page (form 2) Then I have "lblPatID.Text = CType(Session.Item("PatronID"), String)" in form 3. When I close form 3, form 2 opens up but the session variables are not displayed in form 2. Do I have to add read session variable in form 2 also?

Comment: Assuming GVPatID is not null, you can initialize a session variable like this: **Session("PatronID") = GVPatID**  AND then retrieve it like this: **lblPatID.Text = CType(Session("PatronID"), String)** AND if there is no use for it again, you can remove it like this: **Session.Remove("PatronID")**

Comment: Please mark this as an answer if I answered your question. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The answers to your first 3 questions are easy: yes, yes and yes. 
As for the last question: When using Session variables be aware that:

- Session memory is used per user on your server so it has an effect on the scalability, in other words on how many users you can serve per server.
- If you host your application in a server farm, you need to make sure that all servers in the farm have access to the same session state. In this case, you might need to switch to another Session state provider (default is that Session variables are stored in the memory of the server).
- Sessions time out after some time of inactivity. So be prepared that the memory might be gone when a user requests a page.
- You might want to provide an option for a user to clear the session variables if he or she wants to start over.

For a detailed overview about Session memory see this [page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx) on MSDN.

Comment: Thanks Markus, it was a lot of help.

Answer (score 2):

when you use session variables then you will no longer need your second page. the session data is stored at application scope on the server.

when you save/persist the data you can simply save it as follows

```
Session("PatronID") = "GVPatID"
```

when you load/retrieve the data you can simply use it follows

```
lblPatID.Text = Session("PatronID")
```

Any data stored in the session variables is valid can retained until the users browsing session expires, times out or until the window is closed at which point the session is deemed to be over.

It is good practice to dispose of the session data as follows

```
Session.Abandon
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Zaj and Mo.
I made following changes to form 2 page load event and it is working the way i want
        GVPatID = Request.QueryString("value1")

```
    If GVPatID = Nothing Then
        lblPatID.Text = CType(Session("PatronID"), String)
    Else
        Session("PatronID") = GVPatID
        lblPatID.Text = GVPatID
    End If
```